# I'm trying to calculate some expression using multithreading. In some threads value iterResult equals 0. Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to calculate some expression using multithreading. Each thread uses it's own data. In some threads value **iterResult** equals 0. I can't understand why?

```
01:ParameterizedThreadStart expr = threadId =>
02:{
03:    int iThreadId = (int)threadId;
04:
05:    for (uint currentN = nStarts[iThreadId] + 1; currentN < nEnds[iThreadId]; currentN++)
06:    {
07:        uint iterResult = 1;
08:        uint i;
09:
10:        for (i = 1; i < currentN; i++)
11:           iterResult *= currentN + i;
12:
13:        Console.WriteLine("Thread #{0}; currentN = {1}, iterResult = {2}, i = {3}", threadId, currentN, iterResult, i);
14:
15:        results[iThreadId] += (1 / (iterResult * 2 * currentN));
16:    }
17:};
```

Comment: Do you ever have a `-2` in `nStarts`?

Comment: Why are you using uint? int (and breaks down to primitive type int32) is optimized for memory in .net framework- using the uint is actually hurting you in this case

Comment: The least number for `nStarts` is `0`. I used uint, because there no places in program where negative numbers could be met.

Comment: No, wait. I'v just tested the program using int. In some cases `iterResult` can be negative. Which is actually strange as I don't use subtraction. But in most cases it still equals 0.

Comment: *where* is iterResult 0? At line 11?  What is iterResult at line 10 and what are currentN and i?

Comment: Please post more code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would try converting all your uint's to int's... at run time it will have to convert every int/uint for comparing- remove some points of failure.

Comment: Yes... 'where' is it equaling 0? I can't see how line 11 would ever evaluate to 0... As it is set to be '1' 3 lines above, then only drops into the loop if currentN is 2+ .... ?

Comment: `currentN` takes values from 1 to 93 an `i` from 1 to 73

Comment: where are you getting the value to be 0? What line exactly are you seeing this value?

Comment: Here's the full code: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e29f394e7786310c70fe)

Comment: _where are you getting the value to be 0? What line exactly are you seeing this value?_ In line `iterResult *= currentN + i;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. `currentN` takes values from 1 to 93 and `i` from 1 to 73. So, after few iteration of `iterResult *= currentN + i;` iterResult becomes very large. In this case it becomes negative or equal to 0. I just corrected the cycle for:

```
for (k = 1; k < currentN - nStarts[iThreadId]; k++)
{
    if ((iterResult *= currentN + k) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Thread #{0}; currentN = {1}, iterResult = {2}, i = {3}", threadId, currentN, iterResult, k);
}
```

Comment: I was just getting ready to answer this- you are getting arithmetic overflow. You can convert everything to a double or a float and that should fix your problem. but. FWIW- you have an object created to lock on, but you never lock on it- not sure how you are not getting cross thread exceptions.